# How can I install rstudio in windows ubuntu 20.4

Tags: r, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sudo, rstudio-server

I've been trying to install rstudio in ubuntu with this steps:

> wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/bionic/amd64/rstudio-1.4.1717-amd64.deb -O rstudio.deb

> sudo dpkg -i rstudio.deb
> sudo apt-get install -f

> sudo apt install ./rstudio.deb

> sudo apt-get remove rstudio*

But I get this error when I try:

```
rstudio
```

Or

```
sudo rstudio
```

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display                                                                                qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.                              This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.                                                                                                                                                                                                         Aborted

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to install it in WSL? If so, you can't run Linux GUI apps unless you are running [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps). You could install R in WSL and then connect to it [from vscode or RStudio terminal](https://blog.jdblischak.com/posts/wsl-r/). That's probably the easiest thing to do if you need a Linux backend.

Answer (score 0):

you put sudo two time. Try:
`sudo dpkg -i rstudio.deb`
if rstudio.deb is your file name.
for the update if there ask :
`sudo apt -f`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu on Windows I assume you're using WSL2. The problem is that WSL2 (or Docker) doesn't have desktop/GUI so by default you can't run any graphical applications. For that you need some kind of XServer (or special setup for Docker).
I like to use Xserver built in MobaXterm
Alternatively you can use VM or even better if you have disk space and motivation make dual boot and run ROS on Ubuntu natively.